# $A^{-1}=\alpha A+\beta I$

Tags: linear-algebra

A matrix $A$ has characteristic polynomial $(\lambda-2)^3*(\lambda-3)^2$. If $$A^{-1}=\alpha A+\beta I$$ then I have to find $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

What I have done:

As the eigenvalues of $A$ are $2$ of multiplicity $3$ and $3$ of multiplicity $2$, $trace(A)=12$ and eigenvalues of $A^{-1}$ will be $\frac{1}{2}$ of multiplicity $3$ and $\frac{1}{3}$ of multiplicity $2$, giving the trace of $A^{-1}$ to be $\frac{13}{6}$. Obviously $trace(I)=5$. So we get the relation $$\frac{13}{6}=12\alpha+5\beta$$

How to get the exact values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

Comment: The problem should be stated as: "If $A^{-1}=\alpha A + \beta I$..." Otherwise, there are matrices $A$ with the given characteristic polynomial which $A^{-1}=\alpha A+\beta I$ is not true.

Comment: @i707107 I have edited the question likewise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have $A^{-1}=\alpha A+\beta I$, multiply by $A$ and we have $\alpha A^2+\beta A-I=0$. The minimal polynomial must be $ (\lambda-2)(\lambda-3)=0$ so $\alpha=-1/6$ and $\beta=5/6$.